# How would I index a text field that requires explicit characters and wildcards on both ends (postgres)?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to search for a tracking number while only having partial of the value.

I have a tracking number "1Z1234abcde" in my table.

I want to be able to:
select * from tracking_numbers where value ILIKE '%abc%';

I currently have this as a 'text' field type in my table but I am not able to index it correctly so I'm doing a Seq Scan when I use those wildcards.

```
                                             Table "public.tracking_numbers"
          Column          |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                   Default
--------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------
 id                       | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('tracking_numbers_id_seq'::regclass)
 value                    | character varying           |           |          |
```

Full text search and trigram do not solve my problem because I need the characters to be exact, not variations. (ie. an exact tracking_number)

Comment: " I need the characters to be exact, not variations"  What does this mean?  ILIKE '%abc%' is what trigram does.   Is that not what you want?

Comment: Please provide the DDL of this table. My initial suggestion is to read https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning.

Comment: @jjanes I mean that in your example, the"abc" characters must exist exactly and then whatever content can come before or after (ie. wildcards)

Comment: @KevinMeredith I updated my question.  The link you posted suggests not using leading wildcards, which is what i need. I need a leading and trailing wildcard.

Comment: https://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/ or http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/212-PostgreSQL-9.1-Trigrams-teaching-LIKE-and-ILIKE-new-tricks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trigram indexes are exactly what you do want.  In ILIKE '%abc%', the '%' invite variation, while the 'abc' are exactly 'abc'.  Maybe you are thinking of the <-> and % operators, which trigram indexes also support.  But you don't need to use them if you don't want to, you can just use ILIKE.